# how to do special character validation in PHP

Tags: php

I have lot of textarea fields to add comments and quotes. How can I validate these fields. I checked null validation other than null validation what validation I have to do?

Comment: Validate or sanitise? Validation depends on data you want to get - you can be as strict as you like. Sanitising data depends on what you're doing with it - you need to escape database characters before you put it in a database, and html characters before you output it to a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you need to check :

- empty values
- numbers only
- input length
- email address
- strip html tags

**Credit** : [php-mysql-tutorial.com](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/form-validation-using-php.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
!empty( $text ) && strlen( $text ) > 123 && !preg_match('/(<[a-z]+>)/', $text )
```

... and so on...